# In perl, how can I substitute only after and before certain character sequences?

Tags: regex, perl

For example, if I want to substitute all occurrences of double vowels to a single capital vowel only if they occur between `<begin>` and `<end>`, how would I do that?

```
Noot thiis <begin> buut theese need too bee chaanged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer
```

should become

```
Noot thiis <begin> bUt thEse nEd tO bE chAnged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer
```

Comment: $html =~ s/<begin>([^>}+?)<end>/callback($1) /eg; sub callback { my ($txt) = @_;  $txt =~ s/([a-z])\1/toupper($1)/g; return "<begin>$txt<end>"; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expression for case `<begin>` and `<end>` can occur several times:

```
$_="Noot thiis <begin> buut theese need too bee chaanged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer<begin>and thiis <end>";
s/(?:<begin>|\G(?!^))(?(?=<end>)|.)*?\K([a-z])(\1)/uc($1)/ge;
print;
```

Result

```
Noot thiis <begin> bUt thEse nEd tO bE chAnged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer<begin>and thIs <end>
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/1)

Regular expression:

```
(?:<begin>|      # Search from <begin>
   \G            # or position of last match
   (?!^)         #    excluding start of string
)      
(?(?=<end>)|     # If found <end> then test expression between `)` and `|`.
                 # as it is empty (not a <end>)
                 #  - then not matched - end of current search.
  .)*?           # if NOT <end> then any symbol. too many times
\K               # Matched only be considered from this position
                 # replace only after this position
([a-z])(\1)      # 1-character and 1 same
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I needed.  Since I am new to perl regex, can you walk me through what's going on here? In particular, the `\G` , `(?<!^`, and `(?=` ?

Comment: @user2989653 I try to write this in response. although I do not know much English ;)

Comment: Since `^` is a zero-length assertion, you can write `(?!^)` instead of `(?<!^)`.

Comment: This `(?(?=<end>)|.)*?` conditional doesn't do anything. Indeed is the same as `.*?` There is no check for a closing <end>, so it is just triggered by a <begin>

Comment: @sln: `(?(?=<end>)|.)` breaks the contiguity for the next match when the closing tag follows

Comment: I get this regex matching  '<begin> should become become<end> b`ee`come' can you confirm that?

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. Funny thing is @Mike regex matched my comment text under boost's regex engine. But, yup the continuity looks broken under pcre. (I mean with the conditional, it should stop but still will fail if there is no end. I mean it could be nested begin/ends, but still no real end check.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks! Your decision is clearly faster

Comment: I take back it didn't work under boost, I rechecked it and it works. And wow @CasimiretHippolyte what a regex. I'm going to benchmark these two regex's.

Comment: _They are comparable in speed:_ Regex1:   (?:<begin>|(?<!^)\G)(?(?=<end>)|.)*?\K([a-z])(\1)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   7
Elapsed Time:    1.68 s,   1677.93 ms,   1677927 µs


Regex2:   (?:[^<]*<begin>|\G(?!^))[^<a-z]*+(?:<(?!end>)[^<a-z]*|([a-z])(?!\g{-1})[^<a-z]*)*+(*SKIP)\K([a-z])\g{-1}
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   7
Elapsed Time:    1.96 s,   1955.25 ms,   1955253 µs

Comment: @sln: bad news, and this new version https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/11 ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - There might be a backtracking issue with that version::  **1k interval between tags:**  
_Rx Has `[^<]*`_
[without end '<'](https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/12) - [with end '<'](https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/13)
; _Rx Has no `[^<]*`_
[without end '<'](https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/14) - [with end '<'](https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/15)

Comment: @Mike - There is no difference between `(?(?=<end>)|.)*?` and `(?:(?!<end>).)*?`, so if your engine is lower in the food chain, but still supports `\G`, then.. As far as conditionals, the only _real_ use for them is as a flag to see if a _capture_ group matched. If you can find any other use, please tell me.

Comment: @sln It can be used to skip unnecessary blocks (on example, between <end> and <begin>). as it https://regex101.com/r/pI9mN4/6

Comment: @Mike - Ok, I checked it. That condition does more than _skip_ ahead. If there is no other <begin> downstream, the match is disrupted, as the position can never get past the <end>, and `^ .*? <begin>` can only execute once. So, it looks good. I'm trying to do the equivalent without a conditional, let you know if I succeed. @CasimiretHippolyte woah, 409 steps, I got to check this.

Comment: (For @Mike & @CasimiretHippolyte) Ok, I think we have the winner here. This _header_ seems to solve issues `(?:\G(?!^)|(?:[^<]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<begin>))`, no matter what the bottom end is. Obviously, a condition to _skip_ ahead is not needed. Solves performance issues by a one or two factor. I kept getting _too complex_ error in my tester using the `[^<]*(*SKIP)` from Casimir's latest regex, so I forced it, and viola! works and benches as the fastest. I'll make one more comment with a benchmark. https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/17 _and_ https://regex101.com/r/aG1tU9/18

Comment: I threw in the worst case, large distance between  and to the end  _Completed iterations:   10  /  10     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   35_
`Regex1:`   (?:\G(?!^)|(?:[^<]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<begin>))[^<a-z]*+(?:<(?!end>)[^<a-z]*|([a-z])(?!\g{-1})[^<a-z]*)*+(*SKIP)\K([a-z])\g{-1} Elapsed Time:    2.37 s,   2371.80 ms,   2371802 µs
`Regex2:`   (?:\G(?!^)|(?:[^<]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<begin>))(?:(?!<end>).)*?\K([a-z])\1 Elapsed Time:    2.04 s,   2035.29 ms,   2035285 µs
`Regex3:`   (?>^.*?<begin>|\G)(?(?=<end>).*?<begin>|.)*?\K([a-z])\1 Elapsed Time:    3.25 s,   3251.26 ms,   3251259 µs

Answer (score 1):

You can use an *expression substitution* where the expression is another substitution that uses the non-destructive option `/r`

It looks like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'Noot thiis <begin> buut theese need too bee chaanged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer';


$s =~ s{(<begin>.*?<end>)}{ $1 =~ s/([aeiou])\g1/uc $1/egr }esg;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
Noot thiis <begin> bUt thEse nEd tO bE chAnged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer
```

Comment: I'd suggest `\U$1` instead of `uc $1` with the `e` flag on the inner substitution.

Comment: @Tanktalus: Why would you suggest that? I think it's far clearer the way it is.

Comment: One less use of eval.

Comment: @Tanktalus: A single `/e` modifier doesn't use `eval`. It is short for *expression* as I said in my answer. A standard substitution uses the same construct because it is the same as `s/.../ qq{\U$1} /e`, except that you are forced to use a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could extract first the text between those tags and work with it.

However, if you want to use a regex, I can come up with a regex like this:

```
 (.*<begin>)|(<end>.*)|([a-z])\3
```

And a replacement string:

```
 $1$2$3
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pU5oG4/1)**

Of course, you need to capitalize the group `$3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little variation of Borodin's approach simulating a callback method inside a regex-based replacement. The tag matching regex is faster that lazy dot matching pattern since it conforms to the unroll-the-loop principle. The inner substitution is using the `\u` uppercasing operator (makes the next char uppercase):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'Noot thiis <begin> buut theese need too bee chaanged <end> buut noot heeree eitheer';
$s =~ s{(<begin>[^<]*(?:<(?!end>)[^<]*)*<end>)}{ $1 =~ s/([eiaou])\1/\u$1/gr }eg;
print $s;
```

See the [regex demo](http://ideone.com/CurRK6)

The `<begin>[^<]*(?:<(?!end>)[^<]*)*<end>` pattern means:

- `<begin>` - matches a literal string
- `[^<]*`  - zero or more chars other than `<`
- `(?:<(?!end>)[^<]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `<(?!end>)`  - a `<` not followed with `end>`
  - `[^<]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`
- `<end>` - literal text.

Due to the use of negated character classes, no `/s` DOTALL modifier is necessary with this regex, and it is faster than `.*?` based regex since negated character classes grab whole chunks of text matching their pattern in one go without checking each subsequent positions.

Comment: Not my vote, although I don't like it a lot as it doesn't handle line breaks properly.